# Foreach loop failing

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach

[image]

When I debug I get the above data.

Now I am trying to loop through those so as to fill a list (that will be used to populate my model)

However, I get the following error:

[image]

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Put your code and exception message as a text, not as an image..

Comment: @HenkHolterman indeed, but wrong in ways that would give a different message (a NRE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this problem because you try to add an item to the list you are looping through. This is not allowed.

At first glance it looks like you add the item to a different list, but this is not the case: in the first foreach loop you copy references to products from `result` to `lst`. These are just references you copy, so the products in `lst` are the same products as in `result`. This means that `lst.Products.FirstOrDefault()` returns the same object as `result.Products.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: No result is different list from lst.

Comment: I get it now. Thnxx +1